# How to add CanActivate and loadChildren in the same route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I want to lazy load my module but at the same time protect it using canActivate. I tried:

```
{ path: 'dashboard/vendor', canActivate: AuthGuard, loadChildren: 'app/module/dashboard/vendor/vendor.module#VendorModule' }
```

Note that I didn't use children as I have defined the vendor routes in vendor-routing.module using RouterModule.forChild.

But it doesn't work. Any recommendations?

Comment: Try using this: 
`{ path: 'dashboard/vendor', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: 'app/module/dashboard/vendor/vendor.module#VendorModule' }`

Comment: Thanks. This also work, but I guess canLoad is the more appropriate answer.

Comment: For those who are interested. Here's how I applied the answer: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2017/10/how-to-secure-angular-app-using.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [canLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) not canActivate, so if condition is not met it will not load your LazyModule.

```
{ path: 'dashboard/vendor', canLoad: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: 'app/module/dashboard/vendor/vendor.module#VendorModule' }
```

Comment: I have added `canLoad`  still not working, if I add `canActivate` within lazzy loaded component then its working fine.

Comment: did i miss something ? I want to add canLoad/canActivate with `loadchildern`